# Does xubuntu desktop environment installed in mint give same battery performance as original xubuntu os

Tags: linux-mint, xfce, desktop-environment, xubuntu

I have found that Xubuntu provides a better battery life than mint. I want to install xubuntu desktop environment in my mint os. The main reason is saving battery life. I want to know whether xubuntu desktop environment installed on mint provides the same battery performance as the actuall xubuntu os or not.

Thank you